# Loopback many-to-many relation confusion

Tags: angularjs, loopbackjs, angular-loopback

I tried to define many-to-many relation with my Lead and Tag models in my Loopback application

Lead.json

```
"relations": {
    "tags": {
      "type": "hasAndBelongsToMany",
      "model": "Tag"
    }
}
```

Tag.json

```
"relations": {
    "leads": {
      "type": "hasAndBelongsToMany",
      "model": "Lead"
    }
}
```

Now i would like to add a tag to my lead model, my angularService executes this method

```
this.addTag = function (id, tag) {
   if (tag.id) {
      return Lead.tags.link({
          id: id,
          fk: tag.id
      }).$promise
   } else {
      return Lead.tags.create({
          id: id
      }, tag).$promise
   }
};
```

First call works as expected, this adds new tag to my existing lead.

```
Lead.tags.create({id: 1}, {name: 'NewTag'}); //leadId = 1, tagId = 0 (new Tag) indeed there is no ID field, it's just for simplicity
```

Now i would like to add same tag to my new lead.

```
Lead.tags.link({id: 2, fk: 1}); //leadId = 2, tagId = 1 (existing Tag)
```

But this time loopback throws error: `Duplicate entry for LeadTag.id`

Don't know how to add existing tag to new lead. Indeed there is documentation, for example [here](https://strongloop.com/strongblog/defining-and-mapping-data-relations-with-loopback-connected-models/) and there is a method called

```
assembly.parts.add(part, function(err) {});
```

But my lead service doesn't have this `Lead.tags.add` method.

As per source code, Lead.tags.link looks like this

```
    // INTERNAL. Use Lead.tags.link() instead.
    "::link::Lead::tags": {
      params: {
      'fk': '@fk'
      },
      url: urlBase + "/leads/:id/tags/rel/:fk",
      method: "PUT"
    },

    // INTERNAL. Use Lead.tags.unlink() instead.
    "::unlink::Lead::tags": {
      params: {
      'fk': '@fk'
      },
      url: urlBase + "/leads/:id/tags/rel/:fk",
      method: "DELETE"
    }
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Just to be clear, when you use `Lead.tags.add()` are you doing so on an instance or on the model itself? The `add()` method needs to be on an instance of a lead... so something like: `Lead.findById(13, function(err, instance) { instance.tags.add(someTagInstance, ...) });`

Comment: `var lead = Lead.findById({id: 1, filter: { include: 'tags'}});` there is no `add` in _lead.tags_, because it's an array

Comment: Hmm, on the front end that is correct. On the server I think there is a method.

Comment: your first thing to do is run your server with debug strings(https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Setting+debug+strings) to get more information about the error. Try `DEBUG=strong-remoting:* node .`

Comment: Also, your model configuration is good (I just tried it), and so is the REST api call made by angular. The only error I see is with the IDs, please note that id start a 1, not 0. So `NewTag` will have ID 1

Comment: Thanks for Debug version, i will try. `NewTag` doesn't have id field, i just made it for simplicity. `NewTag` is just a plain json object `{"name": "newTag"}`